# Triggering multiple mailto links with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, email, mailto

I'm starting to think that this may not even be possible, but I'm trying to automate a backend management task for myself here by allowing multiple emails to be initiated at once.

I have a table with users. The last column of the table has a drop-down button with mailto links that initiate various emails to the user for that row. The column also has a checkbox next to the button. Here's a simplified snippet:

```
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        User
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="btn-group individual-btn">
          <a class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">
            Email User
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>
              <a class="no-open" href="mailto:user?subject=why&body=etc">
                Why didn't you open?
              </a>
              <a class="no-open" href="mailto:user?subject=why&body=etc">
                Why didn't you click?
              </a>
              <a class="no-open" href="mailto:user?subject=why&body=etc">
                Why didn't you pay?
              </a>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <input type="checkbox" class="selected-row">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      rinse and repeat...
```

At the end of the table I have a button with the same set of actions but the idea for this button is that clicking it will open an email for every selected user (as indicated by the checkbox).

```
    <div class="btn-group master-btn">
      <a class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">
        Email All Checked Users
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li class="email-items">
          <a class="no-open" href="#">
            Why didn't you open?
          </a>
          <a class="no-open" href="#">
            Why didn't you click?
          </a>
          <a class="no-open" href="#">
            Why didn't you pay?
          </a>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

I thought the js might be this easy:

```
    $(".master-btn .email-items a").click(function(e){
      linkClass = "a." + $(this).attr("class").trim()
      $(".selected-row:checked").prev(".individual-btn").find(linkClass)[0].click();
      e.preventDefault();
    });
```

But that only opened an email for the first selected row. So, I thought, well maybe the dom needs space between these clicks, so I'll iterate over each and put a delay in to simulate clicks; but same result: only the first selected row is emailed:

```
    $(".master-btn .email-items a").click(function(e){
      linkClass = "a." + $(this).attr("class").trim()
      $(".selected-row:checked").each(function(i){
        var self = this
        setTimeout(function(){
          $(self).prev(".individual-btn").find(linkClass)[0].click();
        }, 2000*i);
      });
      e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Any thoughts? Will the browser even allow this?

Comment: Yeah, if this doesn't work, the alternative is pretty clear as this is inside a rails app with a robust mail system already in place. I was just hoping to keep this light as it's just an internal tool.

Comment: Isn't it only doing the first one because you select that one with `[0]`? If you want to do all of them, you have to iterate over all the selected elements.

Comment: No. The [0] is required for the click to work due to how Jquery returns link objects. If you look at the code closely, I think it's pretty clear that this doesn't affect the rows or limit the click to the first row. Although, I'm certainly not immune to stupid oversights!

Comment: Whenever I use `$("selector")[0]` it just returns a single DOM element, even if the selector matches multiple elements, and `[1]` gets a different element.

Comment: Interesting. Like I said, I'm clearly not immune to these sorts of stupid oversights. Thanks for pointing this out and making me reexamine it.

Comment: Your layout is a little baffling given the fact that some of your HTML tags are not closed correctly like the `<li>`, `<a>` etc. Could you possibly make a jsfiddle and reproduce this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/gaboom/h81qov5g/

```js
$("#send").on("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $("#iframes").empty();
  $("#links a").each(function() {
    setTimeout($.proxy(function() {
      var popup = window.open($(this).attr("href"))
      setTimeout($.proxy(function() {
        this.close();
      }, popup), 100);
    }, this), 100)
  })
})
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="send" href="#">CLICK TO SEND</a>
<div id="links" class="hidden">
  <a href="mailto:john@example.com">John</a>
  <a href="mailto:sarah@example.com">Sarah</a>
  <a href="mailto:john@example.com">John</a>
  <a href="mailto:sarah@example.com">Sarah</a>
  <a href="mailto:john@example.com">John</a>
  <a href="mailto:sarah@example.com">Sarah</a>
</div>
```

Comment: it's working, but not on Microsoft Edge. On Chrome, it has around 90% of success

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the fix:

```
$(".selected-row:checked").prev(".individual-btn").find(linkClass).each(function() {
    $(this)[0].click();
});
```

When you use `[0]` on a jQuery object, it only returns the first DOM element in the collection, equivalent to `.get(0)`. If you want an array of all DOM elements, you would have to use `.get()` (with no arguments it returns all the elements).

Comment: Nope, still just the first selected item.

Comment: @sibidiba You should post that as an answer.